# Lighting project advice

Tags: led

I am developing a school project to make a rechargeable outdoor light for use at BBQ's etc.

The idea being, on the wall is a mains powered charging dock, with 4 battery powered lights attached.

Once one of the light is removed from the dock, it lights, giving 2-3 hours of light.

Returned to the dock to charge again.

I have the product design part sorted , just need some help with electronics. Would any of you guru's be able to help me out?

I guess the lights would be a series of super bright LED's, running off NiMH rechargeable battery pack in each, these charging through a 'connector' to the charging dock. The simpler the better.

To switch them on automatically , once removed from charging dock ? I am not sure.

Your time and help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick the LEDs first so that you quantify how much power "super bright" 
requires. Once that is defined then you can look at the power control circuitry.

I am not sure of your budget but you may want to look at Li-Ion batteries too.

It should not be difficult to have the light switch on automatically when 
removed from a charging doc.